# Как из EditText получить функцию

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения, математика, android-edittext

Точнее: приложение на андроид должно рисовать график функции, которую вводит пользователь в EditText. Как мне лучше всего забрать эту функцию, чтобы потом обрабатывать?
На ум приходит только - .getText().toString(), а потом с помощью регулярных выражений разбивать строку на части и вытаскивать функции. Это кажется очень сложным, потому как может встретиться композиция функций.. Есть еще варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону [алгоритма Дейкстры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), реализация которого присутствует в библиотеке [exp4j](http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j/).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.